# RichTextBox: Document Content Contains Extra Non-Visible Line Break

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox that needs to accept returns. When I read its document content, it seems to be adding an extra line break. For example, the following code:

```
    TextRange rtbText = new TextRange(rtBox.Document.ContentStart, rtBox.Document.ContentEnd);
    Console.WriteLine(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34) + rtbText.Text + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34));
```

will output

```
    "test
    "
```

even though the visible rtBox content on screen is simply `test` on a single line. I expect the output to be:

```
    "test"
```

EDIT: I am just using the `rtbText.Text` for debugging purposes. The actual usage of that `rtbText` TextRange object will be to save to a MemoryStream using `rtbText.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf)`

Can someone please assist with removing this extra line break. Thanks

Comment: Can you just .trimEnd() on the text?  Or, is that not what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

simply use **Trim()** or even better **TrimEnd()** and it should solve the problem

```
Console.WriteLine(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34) + rtbText.Text.TrimEnd( '\r', '\n' ) + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34));
```

Comment: Thanks. I am just using the `rtbText.Text` for debugging purposes. That `rtbText` TextRange object will be saved to a MemoryStream using `rtbText.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf)` How can I directly trim the TextRange

Comment: you could first change the content as rtbText.Text = rtbText.Text.TrimEnd('\r','\n') and then use rtbText.Save() method

Comment: That worked. Thanks, although I'd like to know why the line break was added in the first place.

Comment: Read the **Remark** section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx , you will get your answer :)

Comment: Actually this won't work for me because using the text property of TextRange won't retain the formatting metadata.